# Architecture of team foundation server (tfs) excel add-in

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, tfs, ssas

We can use Excel to connect to a TFS server and then select a work item query. Based on the query a list of work Items shows up in excel. The data can be edited and published (saved) back to server.

I would like to know the architecture / technology that TFS excel add-in uses to save the data back to TFS.

Main question is does excel access data using which one of the following:

1. a web service that TFS exposes
2. the code in add-in using some TFS client side object model or
3. is it using some SQL server or SharePoint out of the box functionality to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m pretty sure Excel is using TFS SDK libraries that are using TFS Web service in the background to achieve this.

I can tell you for sure that it’s not directly connecting to TFS database – that simply wouldn’t work every time remote connections on TFS database server are disabled. It would also require you to enter user/password for SQL Server instance it needs to connect to.

Here are couple links to get you started in the right direction.

[Extending Team Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Connect to Team Foundation Server from a Console Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286958.aspx) – I’m not 100% sure but I guess excel is using something similar to this…

Answer (score 0):

Hope these links helps you to understand more.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb649552.aspx#self_service_excel

Olap data cube http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb649557.aspx